# Uso de CO en node con node-mysql

Tags: mysql, nodejs, express

quisiera saber si alguien me puede ayudar con el uso de CO en node usando node-mysql para armar consultas donde una depende del resultado de otra.
Esto es lo mismo que usar async / await pero sin necesidad de Babel.
Estoy tratando de hacer una funcion donde me resuelva la promesa con yield y de esta promesa resuelta pasarle ese valor a otra consulta y mostrar los resultados en una vista posteriormente.

Answer (score 0):

Tomando en cuenta el código en https://github.com/sidorares/mysql-co puedes tomar el método `wrap` y adecuarlo a tus necesidades, así:

```
function wrap (fn, ctx) {
  return function () {
    var args = [].slice.call(arguments);
    return function (done) {
      args.push(done);
      fn.apply(ctx, args);
    };
  };
}

// Asumiendo una conexión "conn" más arriba
conn.query = wrap(conn.query, conn);
```

Finalmente, para realizar tu consulta, haces:

```
var co = require('co');
co(function *() {
  console.log(yield conn.query("SELECT 1+1 AS solution"));
  console.log(yield conn.query("SELECT 1+2 AS solution"));
  console.log(yield conn.query("SELECT 1+3 AS solution"));
});
```

**P.D.:** siempre procura proveer un avance de lo que has hecho, así más personas se interesan en responder la pregunta.